# Symfony2 getDateTime returns Null

Tags: php, sql, symfony, datetime, doctrine

I have a class managing members,
All of my datetime fields are returning NULL

```
/**
 * Date/Time of the last activity
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_activity_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $last_activity_at = null;

/**
 * @param datetime $lastActivityAt
 */
public function setLastActivityAt($lastActivityAt)
{
    $this->last_activity_at = $lastActivityAt;
}

/**
 * @return datetime
 */
public function getLastActivityAt()
{
    return $this->last_activity_at;
}
```

Obviously I have data in my database

[image]

However when I retrieve my $member object all the values are there, except the date and datetime fields null

[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: protected $last_activity_at = null - seems a likely culprit, default arguments should be in the constructor. Remove the = null, you don't need it, doctrine will handle that for you.

Comment: no luck sorry @Richard

Comment: Check that you don't have any mapping files under Resources/config/doctrine as they may be interfering with your annotations.  BTW, don't rely on constructor initialization.  The constructor is not called during hydration so you may get unexpected behavior.

Comment: we can only speculate now with the current information, can you confirm that the `$lastActivityAt` contains a valid value of datetime?

Comment: @NickOS May be you show us how are you retrieving and displaying it?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you replace the above with the following?

```
/**
 * Date/Time of the last activity
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(name="last_activity_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $last_activity_at;

/**
 * @param \DateTime $lastActivityAt
 */
public function setLastActivityAt(\DateTime $lastActivityAt)
{
    $this->last_activity_at = $lastActivityAt;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
 public function getLastActivityAt()
 {
     return $this->last_activity_at;
 }
```

Comment: still null sorry Eric

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can set this fields. But judging from your field names I'd suggest [Doctrine LifecycleCallbacks](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

From the docs: Lifecycle Callbacks are defined on an entity class. They allow you to trigger callbacks whenever an instance of that entity class experiences a relevant lifecycle event.

Example:

```
/** @PreUpdate */
public function onLastActivityAtPreUpdate()
{
    $this->last_activity_at = new \DateTime();
}
```

On [Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html) you have a full coverage of several Events, you have to choose what fits you best.

Comment: Thanks Stiven, I am familiar with doctrines Lifecycle Callbacks, I think my issue is that my obj is being lazy loaded from somewhere, my datetime objects are returned if I write a custom query and hydrate to array, however by using the obj getters they always return null.
Not a critical issue at the moment, just a little bug

Comment: @NickOS Is this inside a service?

Comment: Yes, I have an event listener running on the kernel as a service

Comment: Most probably your service priority is too high  and the objects are not hydrated. You can lower it. If I stand corrected the values can vary between - 255 to 255. The default is 0.